# Visualizing the reverse pyramid in a good way

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm trying to draw, for a series of multivariables functions, both the surface plot and the level curves. I am using the following code:

```
contourPotentialPlot1 = 
ContourPlot[Abs[x] + Abs[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
PlotRange -> {-5, 15}, Contours -> 15, Axes -> False, 
PlotPoints -> 30, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, 
ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"];

potential1 = 
Plot3D[Abs[x] + Abs[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.9], LightBlue}, {Opacity[1.9], 
  LightBlue}}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];

level = -5; gr = 
Graphics3D[{Texture[contourPotentialPlot1], EdgeForm[], 
Polygon[{{-3, -3, level}, {3, -3, level}, {3, 3, level}, {-3, 3, 
  level}}, 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
Lighting -> "Neutral"];

Show[potential1, gr, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6}, 
FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]

The output is the following:
```

[image]

How can I modify the code to visualize a "good" reverse pyramid (which is what comes out from the plot of $z = |x| + |y|$)? From the above one it's not clear that it's a pyramid.

Thank you!

I tried to modify the BoxRations parameters, and with something like {1, 1, 2.6} the effect is a bit better, but still it looks like something forces. I would like to observe a "more pyramidical" plot :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) and give it a region of interest over which you want to plot (ie. rotated square in your case).

```
regFunc[x_, y_, z_] := Abs[x] + Abs[y] < 3;

potential1 = 
 Plot3D[Abs[x] + Abs[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5},
   RegionFunction -> regFunc, ClippingStyle -> None, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.9], LightBlue}, {Opacity[1.9], 
     LightBlue}}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
level = 4;    
potential1 = Plot3D[Abs[x] + Abs[y]
   , {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}
   , PlotRange -> {-5, 5}
   , ClippingStyle -> None
   , MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}
   , Mesh -> 15
   , MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5]
   , MeshShading -> {
     {Opacity[.9, LightBlue]}
     , {Opacity[0.5, LightBlue]}
     }
   , Lighting -> "Neutral"
   , ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[
      {{0, 0, level}, {0, 1, level}, {1, 0, level}}]}
   , ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[.4, Gray]
   , BoxRatios -> Automatic
   ];

scp = SliceContourPlot3D[Abs[x] + Abs[y], {z == -level}
   , {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -5, 5}
   , PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-5, -5}}
   , Contours -> Range[0, 6]
   , ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"
   ];

Show[potential1, scp, PlotRange -> All, FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]
```

---

[image]